Is it possible to give Rails' ApplicationCable module a custom name?
Works:
# /channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
  end
end


Throws no method error in inheriting channel that "current_user" is undefined:
# /channels/custom_cable/connection.rb
module CustomCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
  end
end



Do you want to name it differently or put it somewhere else? These are not the same. Also, "doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.

@SergioTulentsev just naming it differently - updated the description.

@mechnicov The goal is to follow my own naming convention, so the second code snippet shall work. Maybe the simple answer is it doesn't work and Rails expects a module ApplicationCable - I just didn't find anything in the guides, neither saying it can nor cannot be customized.

@mechnicov thanks a lot, yes, the config.action_cable part was the missing piece. Where did you find this?

In the rails repository:)

Fair. Looked here and thought I missed it

You can organize your custom namespace (connection and parent channel) such way:
# app/channels/my_custom_namespace/channel.rb
module MyCustomNamespace
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
    # class body
  end
end

# app/channels/my_custom_namespace/connection.rb
module MyCustomNamespace
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    # class body
  end
end

And change connection class:
# config/application.rb
# other configs
config.action_cable.connection_class = -> { MyCustomNamespace::Connection }
# other configs

After that you can create children channels
